# Ranking best features from ORB algorithm

Tags: python, opencv

I cannot figure out how keypoints in the output of the ORB algorithm are ranked in OpenCV.

What I know by testing it on some samples is that it’s not by position on the frame, and I think it’s not as well by the score the algorithm assigned to each keypoint.

My aim would be to rank the keypoints by their score. Best features to worst features. Am I missing something or is it unfeasible without changing the code source of the ORB algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OpenCV source, there's a comment and code that indicates that keypoints are clustered by image pyramid level. See: [OpenCV Orb code on github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/orb.cpp). Within each image pyramid level, keypoints are selected using OpenCV's FastFeatureDetector, which scans by rows then columns, computing corner scores. So the result would be that the output keypoints would be sorted neither by image location nor by keypoint score, as you noted, if you use an image pyramid.  It seems like maybe the Python lib doesn't allow you to set the number of image pyramid levels? But the C++ API does (see: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d95/classcv_1_1ORB.html).

In any case, you should be able to set the number of keypoints retained by using an input argument in Python, so you might not care about ranking them. From what I can tell, you might only want to rank the keypoints by score in order to discard low scoring points, which can be done with the API already.  See: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html#orb-in-opencv

Comment: Thanks for your message and for the insight regarding the pyramid level! 
I actually still want to try to rank them or at least select the 3 strongest/robust features. In fact, I want to get the Affine Transform from one frame to an other of the best vertice I can find on the first frame. Any input would be very valuable! Thanks!

Comment: Usually if you want to get an affine (or other) transform from one frame to the next, you would want to rank features based on their matching scores across frames, not based on their Harris corner scores computed during the feature detection stage on each frame. In other words - I would suggest that you compute a bunch of possible keypoints and compute descriptors for each keypoint, and then try to match the descriptors. See: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

Comment: Yes, you're right! That's actually what I'm right now trying to do! Thanks a lot for your insight on the good practice for feature matching!